# Calculating average for more than one month of data

Tags: google-sheets

I am writing some formulas that will make up a dashboard that allows for a dynamic look-up of change in waiting times for admission into a hospital. In this case, what I want to do is create a lookback period of 1 month, 3 months, 6 months, and 1 year to see how waiting times have changed during this time at a few locations. It's a bit of a complex issue, but the stripped down data and my example code can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lh-FYhp-xItikEOCof0CCdPOi3PoRxQ8DQhDqI9a2to/edit?usp=sharing) (fully shared for editing).

I have successfully gotten the correct formulas for finding 1 month worth of change, but how to apprroach more than 1 month's worth of data eludes me and this is especially problamatic because the date formatting is not standard excel/google sheets data format. As this data will be continously fed into the spreadsheet, I don't think I have the option to modify it either so I think the only option is to come up with some pretty funky formulas that treat months as text. Alternatively, I guess I can also try to make a formula that reformats the text into valid google sheets dates and then use that to make calculations but then while I could probably write that formula, I'd still not know how to get multiple months worth of data processed. Can anyone help take a look at the sheet? (feel free to copy/edit the file if necessary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this:

```
=QUERY({INDEX(SPLIT(Data!A3:A, "T"),,1), Data!B3:C}, 
 "select avg(Col3) 
  where Col1 >= "&DATEVALUE(EOMONTH(TODAY(), -4)+1)&" 
  group by Col2 
  label avg(Col3)''")
```

[image]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Crx_brRdBJ5AVf2nG3dSxnckD3IJFwFMGKB_y8ROv3w/edit#gid=1193280206)

Comment: Thanks, this is very elegant! The cool thing is that I actually get the code as well so don't need to be taught what's happening here.

I appreciate you help player0!